# Problem with image kable extra r markdown

Tags: r, image, r-markdown, pdflatex, kableextra

I'm generating a document with pdf output using rmarkdown. This document contains a column where I am inserting images. The image is inserted correctly, but it comes with the value described in the dataframe.

How do I remove this name (test.png, signature.png), leaving only the image?

```
tabela_1 = kableExtra::kbl(tabela_1, 
                           caption = "Atividades de campo",
                           booktabs = T, 
                           longtable = T, 
                           col.names = nomes_colunas_tabela_1, 
                           align = "c") %>%
  kable_styling(font_size = 10, 
                latex_options = c("repeat_header", "HOLD_position"), 
                position = "center") %>%
  column_spec (1, bold = T, width = "4cm") %>%
  column_spec (6, width = "4cm", image = spec_image(tabela_1$assinatura, 150, 150))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZKdr.png)